# Multiple varibales from a function into an array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I have a function that returns several things and I need to store them into an array seperately.

The code I currently have is like so:

```
Function ADlocation{

Try{
    $ADDetails = Get-ADComputer - Identity $Servername -Properties Description,LastLogOnTimeStamp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ADFail
}
Catch [Exception]{
     return "$($Servername) not in AD"
}
If(!ADFail){
 return (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $(ADDetails.DistinguishedName.Replace("CN=$($ADDetails.Name),","")) -Properties canonicalName).canonicalName

return $ADDetails.Description

return ([datetime]::FromFileTime($ADDetails.LastLogonTimeStamp)).ToString()
}
}


$Output = @()
foreach ($ipAddress in $iplist){
    $Servername = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ipAddress).Hostname
    if(Test-Connection $ipAddress -Quiet){
        $Output += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ip = $ipAddress
            Name = $ServerName
            Pingable = "Yes"
            ADLocation = ADlocation
            AdDescription = ADlocation
            LAstLogOnTime = ADlocation
    }       
    } else {
        $Output +=[PSCustomObject]@{
            ip = $ipAddress
            Name = "N/A"
            Pingable = "No"
        }
    }
  }
  $Output | Export-Csv -path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

I am unsure what i should call to specifically get the "ADlocation", "ADDescription" and LastLogOnTime

Comment: `$Output | Export-Csv ...` -> `$Output | Select ip,Name,Pingable,ADLocation,ADDescription,LastLogonTime | Export-Csv ...`

Comment: This is just giving me the value for ADLocation as opposed to all 3 return values in the function

Comment: `return` exits the function, so all code after that is ignored. Also, when using `try{..}  Catch{..}` you need `-ErrorAction Stop` if you want the code to enter the catch block when an exception occurs.

Comment: You also don't need `return`, it's just *syntactical sugar*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things amiss in your code. As commented, the three return statements in the function. In fact, you don't really need a helper function for this..

Also, there is a syntax error on `- Identity $Servername`, where the space should not be there between the hyphen and the parameter name `Identity`.

Then, if you want to output a valid CSV, you need to specify the same objects with the same properties, both when succeeded and when failed.

I think the easiest way to do this, is to merge success/failed like below:

**Assuming your `$iplist` variable is an array of IP addresses**

```
$OutputPath = 'D:\Test\computers.csv'       # enter the path and filename you want here
# loop over the IP addresses in the list
$Output = foreach ($ipAddress in $iplist) {
    # initialize some variables
    $pingable = 'No'
    $Servername, $ADDetails = $null
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ipAddress -Quiet -Count 1) {
        $pingable = 'Yes'
        # GetHostByAddress is obsolete, use GetHostEntry
        $Servername = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ipAddress).Hostname
        # rather use Filter than Identity so exceptions can be silenced with -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $ADDetails  = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$Servername'" -Properties Description,LastLogOnDate, CanonicalName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    # simply output an object to be collected in variable $Output
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IP            = $ipAddress
        Name          = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ServerName)) { 'N/A' } else { $ServerName }
        Pingable      = $pingable
        ADLocation    = if ($ADDetails) { Split-Path -Path $ADDetails.CanonicalName -Parent } else { 'N/A' }
        ADDescription = if ($ADDetails) { $ADDetails.Description   } else { 'N/A' }
        LastLogOnDate = if ($ADDetails) { $ADDetails.LastLogOnDate } else { 'N/A' }
    }   
}

# output on screen
$Output | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$Output | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```